# JSON file_get_contents empty file

Tags: file-get-contents, json

Why does this output a 0 byte file?

```
<?php
$jsonurl = "http://do.convertapi.com/Web2Pdf/json/?curl=http://stackoverflow.com/";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json);
file_put_contents('converted.pdf', $json_output);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to do following:

```
file_put_contents('converted.pdf', base64_decode($json_output->File));
```

What you actually did is that you retrieved JSON data and decoded it to PHP object. You need to retrieve contents of the "File" property from that object and put it into the file.

Comment: Great thanks, the file is now the correct size but my pdf viewer says it's a corrupt file. Any ideas?

Comment: Opps sorry.. left off the base64_decode. Ignore my last comment as it works perfectly. Thanks again ioseb.

Answer (score 0):

$json_output is an Object but file_put_contents accepts string or array only